# SetPixel crashes after an amount of pixels

Tags: c++, mfc

Im new in MFC/C++ an Im trying to fill my windows with pixels.I found out that there is a function which is called :

> SetPixel(X,Y,RGB(,,));

After I tried to put use it in my loop I found out that this function stops after an amount of pixels.So It don't give me the result I actually want to reach.
Here is my code :

```
void PIXELPROG::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this);

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);


        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;



        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }


        CStatic * XText = (CStatic *)GetDlgItem(IDC_X);
        CStatic * YText = (CStatic *)GetDlgItem(IDC_YWERT);

        CString XYWert;

    for (int x=0,y=0;;)
    {
        GetDC()->SetPixelV(x, y, RGB(y,x,y));
        XYWert.Format(L"%d",y);

        XText->SetWindowTextW(XYWert);

        ++x;
        if (x == 500)
        {
            ++y;
            x = 0;
        }
        if (y == 100)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I also don't get any errors.It is just stopping.
I also tried it with

> SetPixelV()

But didn't helped neither.
Someone got an idea ?

Comment: How big is the windows client-area? What if the coordinates don't go as high as you think? What if you're overwriting the graphics memory of another widget?

Comment: Actually there is enough place there.And how can I check it up ? I thought I have to put this code in the onPaint function.

Comment: You can check the client area dimensions with GetClientRect.

Comment: Just a guess without checking the sources: `SetWindowTextW()` uses the message queue which overflows, blocking further messages. Since you are inside a message handler, the messages can't be handled. What are you trying to do with that loop? Maybe a different approach to solving your real problem would help.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for [`CWnd::GetDC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71eseab0.aspx):

> Unless the device context belongs to a window class, the ReleaseDC member function must be called to release the context after painting.

Since you're not assigning the return value from `GetDC` to anything, there's no way for you to call `ReleaseDC`. Since they're not released, they build up - there's a limit to the total number of GDI objects your application can use, see [GDI Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Once you hit that limit, things go bad very fast (Don't ask me how I know).

If this is in response to a WM_PAINT message, you shouldn't be calling `GetDC` in the first place. You should be using the `CPaintDC` object that you create. As a general rule, don't call the parent `OnPaint` method in your own `OnPaint` handler, because you can only generate a single `CPaintDC`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You have to initialize the DC before. So don't use `GetDC()->SetPixelV(x, y, RGB(y,x,y));`. Make an object before f.x `CDC *pDC = GetDC();` an then use `pDC->SetPixelV(x, y, RGB(y,x,y));`.This is it ! Now it works like a charm :-)

Hopefully this will help someone !

Comment: You must be doing something else, because those two ways are exactly the same. `pDC` is not an object, it's a *pointer* to an object, and the exact same pointer returned by `GetDC` for e.g. `GetDC()->SetPixel(...)`.

Comment: You can try it.Now it is working Im not lying. I declared the 'pointer' outside of my loop. And now it works ... Try it ^^

Comment: That's the difference, you moved the `GetDC()` outside of the loop, which is a smart idea anyway.

Comment: Or you can use BitBlt which is faster for filling the screen.