# GetDC() for HWND before LRESULT function

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to build software with 3d rendering capabilities without using external libraries. I'm a little confused with GetDC() and ReleaseDC(). If I  write the following code after my LRESULT() loop, the program runs for several seconds and then freezes. (I have created two dc's for double buffering with BitBlt())

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

   HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
   HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
   HBITMAP membmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height);
   SelectObject(memdc, membmp);

   ...
   switch (message) {
   ...
   }
}
```

However, according to this link[about SetPixel() crashing after a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884321/setpixel-crashes-after-an-amount-of-pixels), I should move GetDC() outside of the loop. However, I must be doing it wrong, because if I do that...

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP membmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height);


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    TCHAR greeting[] = _T("program_name");
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    SelectObject(memdc, membmp);

...
}
```

... I realize that I cannot SelectObject() outside of the LRESULT loop. In fact, visual studio isn't even going to live with GetDC(hWnd) before the LRESULT loop, I expect because it is created in the first line of the loop. So, woefully, my only option seems to be to replace hWnd with NULL.

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP membmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height);


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    TCHAR greeting[] = _T("program_name");
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    SelectObject(memdc, membmp);

...
}
```

Now I can no longer clear the window, as that relies on InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE). So it runs indefinitely, yet draws outside of the window and cannot erase.

I am new to programming and if anyone can point me in a direction or let me know what's going on, I would appreciate it. :)

Comment: `WndProc` is called as many as 100 times a second, every time the mouse moves and other window messages are generated. Don't create the memory dc in response to every window message. There is a resource leak so you reach 10,000 GDI handle limit and the program breaks. You should create memory dc once, usually in response to `WM_CREATE`. Use `GetDC(0)` for creating memory dc, and `ReleaseDC` shortly after, when `hdc` is no longer needed. Otherwise use `HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps)` for drawing. Hard to make more guesses without [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If I do that, putting HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
   HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
   HBITMAP membmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height);
   SelectObject(memdc, membmp); into the case WM_CREATE: { }, the program doesn't recognize memdc or even hdc when i use them in WM_PAINT. Apparently, WM_PAINT runs first. Do you know what I should do to fix this?

Comment: Declare `HDC memdc;` as global (before the function), then set `memdc = CreateCompatibleBitmap` in `WM_CREATE`, this way `memdc` is available in other functions. You are going to get a lot of headache if you are learning Windows programming before learning C++. Your drawing method is wrong, you shouldn't keep the handle from `GetDC`. Just use the handle and release it within the scope the same function.

Comment: You are lacking fundamental understanding of the anatomy of a Windows application. [Get Started with Win32 and C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows) may turn out to be a useful read.

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to programming and c++ you should first learn the basics of the language and not start with using the WinAPI.

Also your "LRESULT() loop" is not a loop but rather a callback function called by your [message loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383682.aspx).

Concerning your question: Your application should draw its windows content when it receives a [WM_PAINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145137(v=vs.85).aspx)-message.

Comment: Right, but it seems I cannot make device contexts within WM_PAINT, and WM_CREATE isn't being called before WM_PAINT, and I cannot place the code outside of the function, or after the msg loop. It feels like a catch 22, but thanks for the advice. :)

Comment: "it seems I cannot make device contexts within WM_PAINT" why not?

Comment: "*it seems I cannot make device contexts within WM_PAINT*" - that is not true at all. "*WM_CREATE isn't being called before WM_PAINT*" - wrong. WM_CREATE is received *while* the window is being created. WM_PAINT is received when the message loop generates it *after* the window has been created and needs to be drawn onscreen. "*I cannot place the code outside of the function, or after the msg loop*" - yes, you can, you just need to learn the *proper* way to do it. You are taking on too much at one time. Learn how to write proper C/C++ code in general before you learn how to use the Win32 API.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is setup all wrong.  Try this instead:

```
HDC hmemdc = NULL;
HBITMAP membmp = NULL;
HBITMAP oldbmp = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message) {
        case WM_CREATE: {
            HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
            membmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height);
            memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
            oldbmp = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(memdc, membmp);
            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
            break;
        }

        case WM_DESTROY: {
            SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);
            DeleteDC(memdc); memdc = NULL;
            DeleteObject(membmp); membmp = NULL;
            break;
        }

        case WM_ERASEBKGND: {
            return 1;
        }

        case WM_PAINT: {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, width, height, memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            break;
        }

        ...
    }

    return DefWindowProcc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Then, you can simply draw your 3D images into `hmemdc`/`membmp` as needed, and call [`InvalidateRect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect) whenever you want to signal to the OS that the window needs to be redrawn with the latest bitmap.

Though, if you are going to use a memory bitmap for your window, you might consider using [`UpdateLayeredWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556.aspx) instead, and get rid of the `WM_PAINT`/`WM_ERASEBKGND` handlers completely.

Comment: I tried that, but couldn't get it to work. InvalidateRect() wouldn't clear the screen, so when lines moved, they left a trail behind them. I may have messed up. However, what did work indefinitely was creating the hdc and memdc and the membmp at the begining of WM_PAINT, doing draw calls, then deleting everything after EndPaint().